# Can i use two different vendor broadband connections as one in my home?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, ethernet, internet-connection

I have 2 broadband connections, each from a different vendor; Is there a device i can plug both to and have them broadcast a single SSID that i can connect to and never notice a downtime from either if it happens?
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your contribution and yes i only want achieve 24*7 connectivity. Let me restate the design. Each ISP has an outdoor radio and an indoor wireless router. What im looking to achieve is this, i would like to run a connection from the back of both indoor wireless routers to a device with fail-over capability and connect to that device myself...any advise on an indoor wireless router settings that can achieve this?

Comment: *Each ISP has an outdoor radio and an indoor wireless router.* So each router's **wired** LAN is provider's incoming data line. They must be connected to your dual-WAN router (you must buy it), one to WAN1 and another to WAN2, and your network will be connected to LAN. Router may be set to parallel usage (both are used if available, one is used if another fails) or reserved usage (only one is used, but when it fails then switch to another). Of course, you need to disable both ISP's WiFi and use your router's WiFi.

Comment: Thank you @Akina

Comment: Yoy should rephrase your question so its not looking for a hardware recommendation (which is off topic).  Plenty of load balancing routers exist, and ddwrt can be marshalled to do this as well. Nothing you can do "router side only" on a consumer grade router can aggregate or provide transparent error free failover without ISP support but I have done something like this with a VPS and OpenVPN and load balancing and source routing. Its very convoluted to get working.